# Changing grid orientation of a raster

Tags: qgis, raster, xyz

I'm trying to load some XYZ data into a program called OpendTect. However, the orientation of the existing data is different from the grid orientation of the XYZ file. this makes it imposible to load the file correctly.

Is it possible to reorientate / rotate the XYZ grid using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Hi, would you be a little bit more specific what do you mean by the different grid orientation? Can you show an example of the XYZ file? I presume the XYZ file is in ASCII, so I would probably re-formate the file before importing to QGIS.

Comment: The XYZ file is a list of coordinates and values with about 600000 data points. these form a rectangle of data. The data is currently aligned so that Y is North and X is East. the alignment needs to be nearer to Y = 30 degrees. my idea was that i could resample the data in the new orientation.

Comment: Well I am still not sure what you want to do exactly but maybe you want to transform the data to another coordinate system? One which has Y axis shifted by 30 degrees? would this help:http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26084/transform-between-two-3d-cartesian-coordinate-systems or this: http://ads.harvard.edu/books/1989fcm..book/Chapter2.pdf ?